# Error al ejecutar Laravel 5.4 desde directorio public en virtualhost de apache

Tags: php, laravel-5, apache

Buenas tardes,
Quiero visualizar un proyecto en Laravel 5.4 usando un virtualhost de Apache (mi virtualhost funciona ok), pero cuando intento visualizar el contenido del directorio public, tengo el siguiente problema que describo en la imagen, sus comentarios por favor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese es lo que te aparece en el navegador?

Comment: Así es, eso aparece en el navegador. Sabes qué debo hacer?

Comment: Cuál es la URL, estas utilizando la dirección localhost? o configuraste alguna dirección propia?

Comment: Correcto, he creado un virtualhost (que sí está funcionando dado que la dirección del virtual host es: /var/www/html/proyecto/public. El dominio configurado es proyecto.dev y me muestra dicho directorio.

Comment: Sí tienes instalado php? Se está mostrando el archivo como si no estuviera instalado. Comando para instalarlo: `apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt`

Comment: Sí tengo PHP instalado, pero parece que faltaba las otras dos librerías. Te agradezco mucho, ya funciona. Por favor añade tu respuesta para darla como válida. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Respuesta agregada. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que Laravel utiliza varias librerías que no vienen instaladas por defecto en Apache.

Para instalar las librerías puedes ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt
```

Comment: En realidad PHP sí lo tenía instalado, me faltaron básicamente las otras dos librerías, muchas gracias por la ayuda.